# JUnit tests using embedded ActiveMQ throws javax.jms.JMSException: peer stopped

Tags: activemq-classic, junit4, spring-jms

I've a java application that consumes messages from ActiveMQ. I've JUnit test cases that uses embedded ActiveMQ (version: 5.10.0). The test cases execute fine but throws this error post execution. I tried with latest version (5.14.0) and the error is thrown. There is no error with 5.8.0 though. I see a [related thread](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/When-will-activemq-core-5-9-be-present-in-maven-central-repo-td4675087.html) that describes the same issue for ActiveMQ version 5.6.0 but could not see a solution. Appreciate your inputs.

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://my-amq-host");
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(amqConnectionFactory);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(false);
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}
```

---

> 2016-09-23 13:53:37,083 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory][ActiveMQ Connection Executor: vm://my-amq-host#0][301] Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
>   javax.jms.JMSException: peer (vm://my-amq-host#1) stopped.
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1998)
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:2017)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.stop(VMTransport.java:206)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:132)
>       at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:1102)
>       at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$4.run(TransportConnection.java:1068)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: peer (vm://my-amq-host#1) stopped.
>       ... 9 more

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the test code is running in such a way that the connection factory when creating the connection to the VM transport which create an in-VM broker if none is running is actually capturing an instance of an in-VM broker before it has fully cleaned up and gone down.  Without seeing the test code completely it's hard to say for sure though.

It's usually a good idea to have the test create it's own BrokerService that you can control and have the factories use the VM transport with the `create=false` URI option.